# Scikit-learn's (0.22.1) KNNImputer returning wrong number of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

My original data set shape is `(790215,20)` which contains features that have around 60-80% missing values. I decided to use scikit-learn's KNNImputer as follows

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

# Loading the data
dataset = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')

# To avoid 'MemoryError' imputing individually

#Loading the first feature
X = dataset.iloc[:,0].values

#Imputing with default parameters 
imputer = KNNImputer()

#Reshaping to meet the dimensional requirement
X_imp  = imputer.fit_transform(X.reshape(1,-1))
```

Now the shape of `X_imp` is `(1,729026)`

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Why the 790215 changed to 729026.

*Update* :

The `X.shape` is `(790215,)`

`X.reshape(1,-1).shape` is `(1,790215)`

`X.reshape(1,-1)` is `array([[ nan,  97.,  89., ..., 140., 120., 115.]])`

Comment: For debug purposes, can you please print X.shapea and X.reshape(1, -1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you used `reshape` is the problem. You had converted your data into single datapoint by giving `.reshape(1, -1)`. Meaning 1 row with 790215 columns. Hence while transforming the KNNImputer drops the columns which has only `nan` values. This is the reason for the drop.

Instead you need to use `.reshape(-1,1)`, which will make it as 790215 rows and 1 column.

Note: Using single feature for KNNImputer might not work well. Better you can do it with 3-5 features at a time. Also you can take a look at `SimpleImputer`.

Comment: 1) I used  `.reshape(-1,1)` . The `MemoryError` showed up.  2) Again with using more features at once `MemoryError` showed up 3) Will `SimpleImputer` be a good choice for this amount of missing values ?

Comment: Then, `fit` the model using 50 or 60% of your data and then use `transform` in the remaining data.